# How do I fix "gcc: winrespp.rc: No such file or directory" during compiling PAR::Packer on Cygwin?

Tags: perl, cygwin

I have tried to install [PAR::Packer](http://p3rl.org/PAR%3a%3aPacker) in Cygwin for Windows on a 32 bit machine, so I executed `cpan pp`.
I am facing the following problem.

```
gcc-4 -c -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/CORE  -DPARL_EXE=\parl.exe\ -O3 main.c windres -F pei-i386 -i winres\pp.rc -o winres\pp.res
gcc: winrespp.rc: No such file or directory
gcc: warning: '-x c' after last input file has no effect
gcc: no input files
windres: preprocessing failed.
Makefile:735: recipe for target ppresource.coff failed
make[1]: *** [ppresource.coff] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/prabhakaran.srinivas/.cpan/build/PAR-Packer-1.013-eTAwxL/myldr
Makefile:594: recipe for target subdirs failed
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
  RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.81)
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in [myldr/Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/source/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.013/myldr/Makefile.PL):

> ```
> $pre_res = qq(winres\\pp.res);
> $rt_cmd = qq(windres -F pei-i386 -i winres\\pp.rc -o $pre_res);
> $res_cmd = qq(windres -o ppresource.coff $pre_res);
> $res_section = $res;
> ```

and, later,

```
$res_section:
    $rt_cmd
    $res_cmd
```

Under Cygwin's bash, `winres\pp.rc` would be interpreted as `winrespp.rc` instead of `winres/pp.rc`. The correct way would be

```
$pre_res = catfile(winres => 'pp.res');
$rt_cmd = join ' ' => qw(windres -F pei-i386 -i), catfile(winres => 'pp.rc'), '-o', $pre_res;
```

etc.

Comment: Any advice on how to fix this "easily"?  My current technique has been to 'Ctrl+z' once the tar file has been extracted and then to edit the generated Makefile.

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to patch `PAR::Packer` to use *NIX paths.  Such [a patch is available](http://cygwin-ports.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-ports/perl-PAR-Packer;a=blob;f=1.013-cygwin.patch;h=5934dae;hb=HEAD) in Cygwin Ports git.